# Rails i18n different locales for front-end, back-end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, namespaces, internationalization, e-commerce

I am trying to developer commerce solution with back-end and front-end sides. I just finished back-end which is separated by namespaces and realized that i need to separate different locales for every side. So is there a solution how to set locale for front-end and back-end separately? Thanks for advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-and-passing-a-locale

> The locale can be either set pseudo-globally to `I18n.locale` (which uses `Thread.current` like, e.g., `Time.zone`) or can be passed as an option to `#translate` and `#localize`.
>
> If no locale is passed, `I18n.locale` is used:

```
I18n.locale = :de
I18n.t :foo
I18n.l Time.now
```

> Explicitly passing a locale:

```
I18n.t :foo, locale: :de
I18n.l Time.now, locale: :de
```

> The `I18n.locale` defaults to `I18n.default_locale` which defaults to `:en`. The default locale can be set like this: `I18n.default_locale = :de`

So, example from real life (locale, based on Accept-Language HTTP-header (https://github.com/iain/http_accept_language) ):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  #...
  before_filter :set_locale

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale =     http_accept_language.compatible_language_from(I18n.available_locales)
  end

end
```

Comment: I am not sure if u understand me right. My problem is that i set the locale in the admin module and then i work in front-end module and there will be message with invalid locale, because i have different locales in front-end and backend. I set locale for front-end  in application controller and for backend in admin::application controller.

Comment: Documentation points that you can set locale at any place per request scope (`I18n.locale`) or per method call (`I18n.t :foo, locale: :<locale>`). You have set up different locales in different controllers. Any problems? :) I just want to say, that if you set up incorrect locales and see error - then your problem is not that you see error, but that you set up incorrect locales.